# Sitecore Page Preview Asking for non-valid Site in Multi-Site Setup

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have a Sitecore multi-site setup running on Sitecore 6.5. Currently, the page preview in the preview tab of the content editor gives us back error 404 because it is passing invalid url parameters.

The url it is attempting to reach is:

```
http://preview-site1.com:80/sitecore/content/Home-site1/P/F/BM/WaystoMakeYourPracticeGreen?sc_site=website&sc_lang=en&sc_mode=preview&sc_duration=temporary&sc_device=%7bFE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3%7d
```

This url is incorrect because it specifies the parameter `sc_site=website`. We do not have a site element declared with the name website except in our forms.config (for WebForms for marketers). Removing this parameter or chaning it to `sc_site=site1` makes the path valid. If I remove the `<site name="website">` element from our forms.config file, the page preview uses a completely different url structure that returns a grey background.

How do I convince the Sitecore page preview to use the correct url (or omit the parameter altogether)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the `<site />` element with the name `website` is special in Sitecore and necessary for features to work correctly in a multi-site setup. The `website` site should be a catch all for the sites running on your Sitecore instance.

EDIT: The page preview engine specifically requests the site `website` expecting this ( site named website ) to be correctly configured. Sitecore hints at this in their documentation on the SDN but does not mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into the Sitecore authoring interface under the URL you want to preview. It cannot determine the context site to preview otherwise. E.g. `site1.com/sitecore/` vs. `site2.com/sitecore/`

Comment: Thanks Mark! 

We actually managed to solve this problem by adding a site entry for "website" with its root being the parent of our multiple sites. From here, the content editor preview tab now works because it specifically looks for the site "website". I tried that on a hunch from reading Sitecore's how-to on running multiple sites.